# Managing GCKDevices on app when user switch TV source

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

Google Chrome cast api of ios have the following methods of device discovery

```
- (void)deviceDidComeOnline:(GCKDevice *)device {


// : manipulate UI
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

```
- (void)deviceDidGoOffline:(GCKDevice *)device {

//: manipulate UI 
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}
this runs fine at the start of application and the devices are added to UI normally because I add a listener to it and start the scan when **startScan** method that typically runs for 5 seconds but if now i switch the source from TV or unplug the device from TV device **deviceDidGoOffline** method is not called. How can I have a notification posted once the device have gone offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the SDK which affects this feature. It will be addressed in the next release.

Comment: It seems that it was not fixed in the current release? or am I missing something