# Chromecast button not hiding

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cast

I am using google casting through my app. It is working good but I am not able to hide the casting button when the cast device goes offline. It hides automatically but after a long time. How can I hide it immediately. Is there a way to get the notifications from the device scanner class.

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding listener

```
[self.deviceScanner addListener:self];
[self.deviceScanner startScan];

#pragma mark - GCKDeviceScannerListener
- (void)deviceDidComeOnline:(GCKDevice *)device {
  NSLog(@"device found!! %@", device.friendlyName);
 [self updateCastIconButtonStates];
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDiscoverDeviceOnNetwork)]) {
[self.delegate didDiscoverDeviceOnNetwork];
 }
}

- (void)deviceDidGoOffline:(GCKDevice *)device {
  [self updateCastIconButtonStates];
}
```

**Update**

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167241/managing-gckdevices-on-app-when-user-switch-tv-source).